# Vue and Stripe causing Invalid Dom Element error. But the dom element is correctly rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments, v-for

I'm trying to intergrate stripe elements in a vue app. I have successfully done so previously. But now i'm trying to do it again in a v-for loop.

I've made sure that the stripe element is only loaded after the Dom element is rendered. The Dom Element is in a v-for loop. Outside of this loop it works fine. But inside the loop I get an error:

> Error: Invalid DOM element. Make sure to call mount() with a valid DOM element or selector.

This is odd. When I log the DOM element before mounting the Stripe Element. Instead of returning the element, it returns an array containing the element. If I try to access that array I get the same error.

If I log the working version, without the v-for, I get the element, no array. Any idea what is going on here? Here's the relevant code:

```
  <div>
    <div ref="card" class="card-input"></div>
    <button v-on:click="purchase(i)">Purchase</button>
  </div>
```

And the js

```
 mounted () {
   card = elements.create('card')
   console.log(this.$refs.card)
   card.mount(this.$refs.card)
 }
```

Comment: user https://codesandbox.io/s/vue, to see an example and to help you.

Comment: I don't understand. That is just an example of vue, not of any specific issue.

Comment: set an example in the online editor, to help you.